# how to apply react-loadable only in production?

Tags: reactjs

In my project, I used `react-loadable` for code splitting and improve the performance. But, using this in development mode slows the performance.

Also, it downloads the chunks around `11.2mb` file size. Before, using `react-loadable` it's size is `3.7mb`.

In production it's efficient one. main js file size is `2.7mb`.

So, Is there any method to apply the `react-loadable` only in production mode.